# CORS block in firebase cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, cors

I'm implementing a cloud function to get results from BigQuery. My functions/index.js code below

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});

exports.getBigQueryData = functions.region('europe-west3').https.onRequest((req,res) => {
  cors(req,res,() => {
    const bigquery = new BigQuery({
      projectId: 'neon-opus-585',
      keyFilename: 'service_account_bq.json'
    });
    const query = "SELECT * FROM `xxxx`";
    bigquery.createQueryJob({query: query}).then((data) => {
      const job = data[0];
      return job.getQueryResults();
    })
    .then(results => {return res.send(results)})
    .catch(error => {console.log(error)})
  })
})
```

When i only deploy / test the function, everything runs OK, but when I use it from inside my application I get the following error

> Access to fetch at 'https://xxxx.cloudfunctions.net/xxxx' from origin 'http://localhost:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

As you can see I tried importing the cors package and implement it in my function as suggesting by several posts here but it is still not working.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look into [Handling CORS requests](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_cors_requests), there you have an example about this:

> To handle a preflight request, you must set the appropriate Access-Control-Allow-* headers to match the requests you want to accept:

```
exports.corsEnabledFunction = (req, res) => {
  // Set CORS headers for preflight requests
  // Allows GETs from any origin with the Content-Type header
  // and caches preflight response for 3600s

  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    // Send response to OPTIONS requests
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');
    res.status(204).send('');
  } else {
    res.send('Hello World!');
  }
};
```

And [Authentication with CORS](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#authentication_and_cors):

If you plan to send a request with an Authorization header, you must:

1. Add the Authorization header to Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
2. Set the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header to true.
3. Set a specific origin in Access-Control-Allow-Origin (wildcards are not accepted).

```
exports.corsEnabledFunctionAuth = (req, res) => {
  // Set CORS headers for preflight requests
  // Allows GETs from origin https://somedomain.com with Authorization header

  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://somedomain.com');
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    // Send response to OPTIONS requests
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization');
    res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');
    res.status(204).send('');
  } else {
    res.send('Hello World!');
  }
};
```

Comment: Where do i put my function code. Here is my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68646425/firebase-function-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-req